# PHP search url request

Tags: php, url, request

I need some help with this I have for example index.php and and i need to make it something like. 
someone access:

```
index.php?search=blbla 
include search.php
else
include home.php
```

I need an advice with this thanks

Comment: Learn about `if` statement and `$_GET` table.

Comment: it might pay in future to post in pseudocode, so that people can more clearly understand what you are trying to say. Something like if url contains '?search=' then include search.php - else include home.php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
if (isset($_GET['search'])) include('search.php');
else include('home.php');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$sq = $_GET['search']; //$_GET['']
if (isset($sq) && $sq != '') {
include('search.php');
} else {
include('home.php');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to see if the variable is set. e.g.

```
if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    include "search.php";
}
else {
    include "home.php";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//if($_GET['search'] > ""){ // this will likely cause an error
if(isset($_GET['search']) && trim($_GET['search']) > ""){ // this is better
   include ('search.php');
}else{
   include ('home.php');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
if (isset($_GET['search']))
  include 'search.php';
else
 include 'home.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to check if a `$_GET` is set and if it actually equals something like so:

```
if(isset($_GET['search']) && strlen(trim($_GET['search'])) > 0): include 'search.php'; 
else: include 'home.php';
```

This will avoid the problem of putting in the `$_GET` variable but not actually setting it.

Answer (score 0):

When using [`isset()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) you need to be aware that with an empty GET variable like this `script.php?foo=` that `isset($_GET['foo'])` will return **TRUE**
Foo is set but has no value.

So if you want to make sure that a GET variable has a value you might want to use [`strlen()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) combined with [`trim()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) instead...

```
if (strlen(trim($_GET['search'])) > 0) {
    include('search.php');
} else {
    include('home.php');
}
```

Also you might want to use [`require()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) instead of [`include()`](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). A PHP fatal error is generated if search.php cannot be "required" with just a PHP warning if search.php cannot be "included".